# mariadb-backup (restore) basics questions -- which DBs are required to backup, & what's the right restore procedure/order for multiple, separate DBs?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, backup, database-restore

I'm running a MariaDB 10.5 server.

I have 2 test databases created,

```
mariadb -e "show databases;"
    +----------------------------+
    | Database                   |
    +----------------------------+
    | information_schema         |
    | mysql                      |
    | performance_schema         |
    | test1                      |
    | test2                      |
    +----------------------------+
```

I'm trying to get straight on what I do & don't need to backup for a complete restore.

(1) When I backup all DBs

```
mariadb-backup --backup --target-dir="all"
```

I end up with

```
tree -L 1 all/
    all/
    ├── aria_log.00000001
    ├── aria_log_control
    ├── backup-my.cnf
    ├── ib_buffer_pool
    ├── ibdata1
    ├── ib_logfile0
    ├── mysql/
    ├── performance_schema/
    ├── test1/
    ├── test2/
    ├── xtrabackup_binlog_info
    ├── xtrabackup_checkpoints
    └── xtrabackup_info
```

IIUC, I can completely restore my entire server from this one, complete backup.
To any machine running MariaDB, but only to the SAME version of MariaDB server.

Is that correct?

(2) In that backup I don't get the "information_schema", but DO get the "performance_schema". Not sure why.

Are each of the three DBs

```
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
```

REQUIRED for restoration?  I've got lots of mixed messages on this one from online posts. And didn't find yet a "do this" in the main docs.

(3) If I backup the testDBs seperately

```
mariadb-backup --backup --databases="test1" --target-dir="bkup1"
mariadb-backup --backup --databases="test2" --target-dir="bkup2"
```

I get

```
tree -L 1 bkup1/ bkup2/

    bkup1/
    ├── aria_log.00000001
    ├── aria_log_control
    ├── backup-my.cnf
    ├── ib_buffer_pool
    ├── ibdata1
    ├── ib_logfile0
    ├── test1/
    ├── xtrabackup_binlog_info
    ├── xtrabackup_checkpoints
    └── xtrabackup_info

    bkup2/
    ├── aria_log.00000001
    ├── aria_log_control
    ├── backup-my.cnf
    ├── ib_buffer_pool
    ├── ibdata1
    ├── ib_logfile0
    ├── test2/
    ├── xtrabackup_binlog_info
    ├── xtrabackup_checkpoints
    └── xtrabackup_info
```

If I was to destroy the original server's data, and restore JUST from these two,
that would NOT be enough to get back up & running, right?
For that I also need 1 or more of the DBs I asked about in (2)?

(4) If I've taken 2 separate backups, like in (3), they each contain

```
├── aria_log.00000001
├── aria_log_control
├── backup-my.cnf
├── ib_buffer_pool
├── ibdata1
├── ib_logfile0
├── xtrabackup_binlog_info
├── xtrabackup_checkpoints
└── xtrabackup_info
```

Even those are the same names, if they've been taken at different times IIUC they can have different contents.

If I restore "bkup1/" to the main server, it overwrites those files on the server.
Then if I restore "bkup2/", it again overwrites those files on the server.

What's the right way to restore separate DBs' backups, and not end up clobbering the data needed on the main server?

Comment: I suggest to read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partial-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/ attentively, apparently the "Restoring" parts. Your backup is partial, so you do not overwrite the whole data directory